# Blazor. Obtener index de una lista despues de hacer un drag and drop

Tags: lista, blazor

Estoy haciendo una app en Blazor Server en la cual creo atributos de una clase y la listo. para esto voy cargando la lista y la muestro en un MudList
Quiero hacer drag and drop sobre esa lista.

```
 // Objeto
 namespace Generador_ABM.Data
{
 public  class Clase
 {
     public string? NombreAtributo { get; set; }
     //Dataype Enumerador
     public DataType TipoDato { get; set; }
     public bool AceptaNull { get; set; }
     public string? ValorPorDefecto { get; set; }

     public Clase() { }

     public List<Clase> listaAtributos=new List<Clase>();
     public void AgregarAtributo(string nombreAtributo,DataType tipoDatoSeleccionado,bool aceptaNull, string valorPorDefecto)
     {
         listaAtributos.Add(new Clase
         {
             NombreAtributo = nombreAtributo,
             TipoDato = tipoDatoSeleccionado,
             AceptaNull = aceptaNull,
             ValorPorDefecto = valorPorDefecto
         });
     }
 }
}
```

Enumerador con tipos de datos

```
 public class EnumTipoDato
    {
        //Propiedades
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DataType Type { get; set; }

        //Constructor
        public EnumTipoDato(string name, DataType type)
        {
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
        }

        //Enumerador con tipos de datos
        public enum DataType
        {
            String,
            Int,
            Double,
            Bool,
            Char,
            DateTime,
            Decimal,
            Float,
            Long,
            Short,
            Byte,
            SByte,
            UInt,
            ULong,
            UShort
        }
```

Pagina razor

```
@page "/"
@using Generador_ABM.Data;
@using static Generador_ABM.Data.EnumTipoDato;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<MudPaper Class="d-flex justify-content-around px-1" Elevation="0">
    <h2>Generador de Clase</h2>
    <h2>Lista de aributos</h2>

</MudPaper>
<MudGrid >
<MudItem xs="8">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-center py-4" Elevation=5>
     
        @*Formulario de Clase*@

        <MudForm @ref="form" @bind-IsValid="@success" @bind-Errors="@errors" ReadOnly="false">
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Agregue los atributos de la clase y el tipo de dato</MudText>
            <MudTextField Class="col-4" @bind-Value="nombreClase" Label="Nombre de la clase"
                          Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                          Margin="Margin.Dense"
                          Required="true"
                          RequiredError="Ingrese el nombre de la clase"></MudTextField>
            <MudSpacer />
            <br />
            <MudGrid>
                <MudItem>
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Atributos</MudText>
                    <MudTextField Class="col-12" @bind-Value="atributo" Label="Nombre de atributo"
                                  Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                                  Margin="Margin.Dense"
                                  Required="true"
                                  RequiredError="Ingrese el nombre del atributo"></MudTextField>

                </MudItem>
                <MudItem>
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Tipo de dato</MudText>
                    <MudSelect Class="col-12" TValue="DataType" @bind-Value="tipoDatoSelecionado" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense">
                        @foreach (DataType dataType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DataType)))
                        {
                            <MudSelectItem Value="dataType">@dataType</MudSelectItem>
                        }
                    </MudSelect>
                </MudItem>
                <MudItem Class="ml-4">
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Acepta null</MudText>
                    <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="@aceptaNull" Color="Color.Primary" Style="margin:auto;" />
                </MudItem>
                <MudItem Class="ml-8">
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">Valor por defecto</MudText>
                    <MudTextField Class="col-12" @bind-Value="valorPorDefecto" Label="Valor por defecto"
                                  Variant="Variant.Outlined"
                                  Margin="Margin.Dense"
                                  ></MudTextField>
                </MudItem>
                <MudItem style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; margin-top:40px;">
                    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Disabled="@(!success)" Color="Color.Primary" @onclick="Agregar">Agregar</MudButton>
                </MudItem>
            </MudGrid>
            <MudItem style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; margin-top:2rem;">
                <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Disabled="@(!success)" Color="Color.Primary" @onclick="Agregar">Generar Clase</MudButton>
            </MudItem>
        </MudForm>
    </MudPaper>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="4" >
        @*Lista de la clase*@
        <MudPaper Elevation=5 Class="d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-8">
              <MudList>
                @foreach (var atributo in lstAtributos)
                {
                    @*Se interpola todos los atributos del listado para mostrar*@
                    <MudListItem T="string" style="border: 1px solid #E0E0E0; border-radius:1rem;">
                        @*Botom para eliminar*@
                        <MudFab Color="Color.Primary" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" Size="Size.Small" OnClick="(() => Eliminar(atributo))" />

                        @*Valor*@
                        @($"Propiedad:{atributo.NombreAtributo} - Tipo:{atributo.TipoDato} - Acepta Nulo:{(atributo.AceptaNull ? "?" : "")} - Valor por defecto:{atributo.ValorPorDefecto}")
                    </MudListItem>

                }
             </MudList>
        </MudPaper>
    </MudItem>
   
   
    <MudItem xs="8">
        <MudPaper Class="d-flex align-center justify-center mud-width-full py-8">
            @*Clase*@
           
        </MudPaper>
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>


@code
{
    //Para manejo de errores formulario
    MudForm form;
    bool success;
    string[] errors = { };

    //Para valores de formulario
    public string nombreClase;
    public string atributo;
    public bool aceptaNull;
    public string? valorPorDefecto;

    //Instancia el objeto y declaro el using static de la clase EnumTipodato para acceder al ella.
    public DataType tipoDatoSelecionado;

    //Instancia de clase
    Clase clase = new Clase();
    //Declaro un listado de Tipo Clase
    List<Clase> lstAtributos = new List<Clase>();

    public void Agregar()
    {
        //se invoca el metodo con los argumentos que ingresan por formulario
        clase.AgregarAtributo(atributo, tipoDatoSelecionado, aceptaNull, valorPorDefecto);
        CargarListado();
        LimpiarForm();

    }

    public void CargarListado()
    {
        lstAtributos=clase.listaAtributos;
    }

    public void LimpiarForm()
    {
        atributo="";
        aceptaNull=false;
        valorPorDefecto=string.Empty;
    }

    public void Eliminar(Clase atributo)
    {
        lstAtributos.Remove(atributo);
    }

   
   

}
```

Queda implementar el el Drag and Drop. Del cual aun no me decido por un paquete en particular porque me encuentro buscando un metodo el cual me permita obtener los index de los elementos del MudList (MudPaper de la izquierda) para modificar el orden de lstAtributos.
La idea es generar un archivo .cs para con el orden que el usuario desea sin importar el orden en que los creo.
Ejemplo. Si crea tres objetos a la lista lstAtributos[objeto1,objeto2,objeto3] y luego en el MudList haga un drag and drop y el objeto1 pasa al tercer lugar y el objeto3 pase al primer lugar, entonces mi lstAtributos se modifica [objeto3,objeto2,objeto1]

Esto tiene que repercutir en la lista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿La lista? Cuál lista? No vemos código de ninguna lista, de hecho, no vemos nada de código. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar la estructura de datos que tienes, en formato texto, porque las imágenes de código no son bien recibidas. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio por la observacion. Mañana desde el laburo actualizo el posteo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

**1.- Drag and Drop en Javascript**

Blazor Wasm está limitado por lo que puede hacer javascript y HTML, por lo que es bueno entender como funciona el drag and drop en html+js, además muchos vienen de ese mundo, por esto partiré desde como se hace en html+js hasta llegar a blazor

Aquí un ejemplo básico, donde se arrastra un "Item" y al dejarlo caer los coloca por debajo del otro "Item"

```js
function OndragStart(){
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Item", event.target.id);
}

function OnDrop(){
  var itemId = event.dataTransfer.getData("Item");
  event.target.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',document.getElementById(itemId));
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">

<div id="Item_1"
     draggable="true"
     ondragover="event.preventDefault()"
     ondragstart="OndragStart()"
     ondrop="OnDrop()">
    ITEM 1
</div>

<div id="Item_2"
     draggable="true"
     ondragover="event.preventDefault()"
     ondragstart="OndragStart()"
     ondrop="OnDrop()">
    ITEM 2
</div>

<div id="Item_3"
     draggable="true"
     ondragover="event.preventDefault()"
     ondragstart="OndragStart()"
     ondrop="OnDrop()">
    ITEM 3
</div>


</div>
```

El funcionamiento es siempre igual:

- Seteamos cada item como `draggable="true"`
- El evento `ondragover` lo dejamos como `event.preventDefault`
- En el evento `ondragstart` guardamos el item que se arrastra o un identificador del mismo, esto se hace en un especie de contenedor llamado "dataTransfer"
- En el evento `ondrop` proporcionamos la lógica cuando se deja caer el Item, ya sea intercambiarlo por otro, agregarlo a un contenedor, etc

**2.- Los problemas**

Para llevar esto a Blazor existen 2 grandes problemas. El primero es que el intercambio que hemos hecho es solo visual y la lógica de blazor no funciona de esa manera, Blazor tiene datos que generan algo visual. Y el segundo es que (hasta donde yo entiendo) el objeto "DataTransfer" en Blazor no está enteramente implementado, faltándole funciones importantes. Pero si compredemos que el DataTransfer solo lo estamos usando para guardar los que estamos arrastrando, es fácil reemplazarlo por otro mecanismo

**3.- Reformulando el ejemplo**

Aquí otro ejemplo, pero ahora:

- Generamos la vista a parir de datos
- Reemplazamos el "Datatransfer" por una variable que nos guarde el item arrastrado
- Creamos una función `Swap` que intercambie 2 objetos de una lista

```js
class Clase
{
  //Solo usaremos una propiedad, que será "NombreAtributo"
   constructor(NombreAtributo ){
     this.NombreAtributo =NombreAtributo ;
   }
}

let lstAtributos  = [new Clase("Item1"),new Clase("Item2"),new Clase("Item3")];

//redibuja
function StateHasChange(){
  contenedor.innerHTML ="";
  
  for(let i=0; i< lstAtributos.length; i++){
     contenedor.innerHTML +=`<div draggable="true"
     ondragover="event.preventDefault()"
     ondragstart="OndragStart(${i})"
     ondrop="OnDrop(${i})">
    ${lstAtributos[i].NombreAtributo}
    </div>`;
  }

}

Array.prototype.Swap = function(i1,i2){
  let aux = this[i1];
  this[i1] = this[i2];
  this[i2] = aux;
}


let ItemDrag={}; //aqui guardamos el item que se está moviendo

function OndragStart(item){
  ItemDrag = item;
}

function OnDrop(itemDrop){
  lstAtributos.Swap(itemDrop,ItemDrag);
  StateHasChange();
}

StateHasChange();
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">

</div>
```

**4.- Ahora si, en Blazor**

El ejemplo anterior es muy fácil llevarlo a Blazor, es casi directo

```
@foreach (var item in lstAtributos)
{
    <div draggable="true"
     ondragover="event.preventDefault()"
     @ondragstart="() => OndragStart(item)"
     @ondrop="() => OnDrop(item)">
    @item.NombreAtributo
    </div>
}

@code{

    //clase solo de ejemplo
    public class Clase
    {
        public string NombreAtributo { get; set; }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //inicializamos la lista con datos de ejemplo
        lstAtributos.Add(new Clase() { NombreAtributo = " Item 1" });
        lstAtributos.Add(new Clase() { NombreAtributo = " Item 2" });
        lstAtributos.Add(new Clase() { NombreAtributo = " Item 3" });
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }


    private List<Clase> lstAtributos { get; set; } = new List<Clase>();

    private Clase? ItemDrag { get; set; }

    private void OndragStart(Clase clase) => ItemDrag = clase;

    private void  OnDrop(Clase itemDrop) => lstAtributos.Swap(itemDrop, ItemDrag);

}
```

Y la clase de extensión para hacer el SWAP

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void Swap(this List<Clase> lista, Clase item1, Clase item2)
    {
        var aux = item1;
        int index2 = lista.IndexOf(item2);
        lista[lista.IndexOf(item1)] = item2;
        lista[index2] = aux;
    }
}
```

---

Todo esto es de forma genérica, pero tu estas usando una librería de 3ros (que yo no he ocupado nunca), seguramente en los eventos `ondragstart` y `ondrop` no vas a tener problema, pero en el `ondragover` y `draggable=true` que son indispensables vas a tener que usar algo como `UserAttributes`

Por último 2 recomendaciones

En C# tienes:

- Propiedades: Son los que tiene {get;set}
- Campos: Son sin {get;set;} (la variable global de toda la vida)
- Atributos: Van arriba de propiedades, funciones, clases y estan encerrados por corchetes, algo as:

```
[esto_es_un_atributo]
public int propiedad {get;set;}
```

Lo digo porque tu estas llamando atributos a las propiedades.

Por último tu tienes una enumeración con Tipos primitivos, te recomiendo que la cambies a una lista o un diccionario, porque si quieres evolucionar la APP a tipos dinámicos se te va a complicar.

Comment: Hola Yuseef. Muchas gracias. Me re sirvio la ayuda y toda la explicacion. Voy a tener en cuenta las recomendaciones. Hizo justo lo que queria. Lo adecue a lo que tenia y funciona de 10. Solo estoy teniendo un inconveniente en mi proyecto. Cuando arrastro se mueven todos los item. Osea el seleccionado y el reto de la lista. La funcion la hace Sera cuestion de ver como lo separo. Te agradezco una vez mas por la ayuda.

Comment: @LuisSanchez Me alegro haber podido ayudarte, si tienes mas problema con esto puedes formular otra pregunta ya con el código implementado. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: Si, listo Uessef, No suelo pasar mucho por aqui, pero siempre es util. Se me olvido comentarte que ya tambien contemplamos lo de propiedades dinamicas u otras opciones. Te la comento igual por las dudas que a vos se te ocurra algo. 
Lo que pensamos es colocar un colocar en el combobox la opcion "Otros" y si es elegido mostrar en el form un campo de texto para de forma manula ingresar la propiedad y el tipo de variable que se desee. Como al final esto es solo texto plano lo pasamos despues como linea al archivo.

Comment: @LuisSanchez Yo una vez hice algo muy parecido, llevándolo a tu caso, lo que hacia es que si por ejemplo creaba la clase `Persona`, esa clase ahora aparecía en el combobox, esto te permite crear clases que tengan propiedades que sea de tipo `Persona` o lo que sea que tu hayas creado anteriormente y así tener clases complejas

Comment: Uhmm. Interesante. Una clase padre y que las clases hijas herenden de el. Buena. En el caso nuestro. Baf, la tarea que me di, es crear esto para luego hacer todo un ABM de esa clase. Usamos MudBlazor, asi que luego de esto tengo que decirle que van tipos de campos van hacer para desplegarlo en un formulario. Ej: nombre sera un MudTextField o un checkbox. A proposito. Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con la adaptacion del codigo que sugeriste. Te consulto. Debo consultar de nuevo en este mismo hilo o debo abrir una nueva pregunta?